# questions method returns error 4000

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm getting error 4000 on every endpoint on questions method (with key):

http://api.superuser.com/1.0/questions?sort=votes&pagesize=30&page=1&key=stackprinterkey

the only endpoint not affected is stackoverflow:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?sort=votes&pagesize=30&page=1&key=stackprinterkey

`key` parameter is the first suspect.

Comment: I'm getting the error 500 with my key, and no error without my key.

Comment: Indeed. I'm getting errors across the board on the "main sites" with my key. stackauth seems to be working fine.

Comment: Reproduced, working on it.

Comment: ++ you beat me to it. thats what I get for building up a static cache of returns on disk to feed to soapi's request cache for testing. ;-)

Comment: @code looool ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS got a little screwy there cutting off some of our back end.  In particular, the back end that manages [app] keys.

Its been fixed now.